# Как узнать что telephonyManager.getDeviceId(); не Null

Tags: java, android, null, imei

Подскажите как узнать что IMEI существует? У меня в приложении IMEI присваивается переменной

```
deviceIMEI = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Если же приложение запускать на планшете без возможности установки сим карты то приложение падает при отправке значения переменной `deviceIMEI` на сервер. Планшета под рукой нет и я не могу понять что происходит, то ли `telephonyManager.getDeviceId();` просто равен 0, либо его просто не существует. Причем Если приложение запускать на эмулятор где imei = 0 то приложение не падает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть код метода [`getDeviceId()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/donut-release/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java), то можно увидеть, что он не пробрасывает никаких исключений, но, если что-то пошло не так, то он возвращает `null`. Исходя из этого, можете просто проверять результат на `null`:

```
deviceIMEI = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
if (deviceIMEI != null) {
    // some actions
} else {
    // another actions
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Вот я тупанул, про самое простое забыл, это мой загон. Только проверять буду не переменную deviceIMEI а сам метод: ` if (telephonyManager.getDeviceId() != null) `

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй обернуть в обработчик исключений:

```
try {
    deviceIMEI = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SIM-карта не найдена" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Скорее "ошибка получения айди устройства"

Comment: Да ошибка в получении айди устройства. Но обработчиком исключений тоже можно решить проблему. Спасибо за подсказку.